# sed search and replace html tag

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I m trying to search and replace a specific tag which is following:

```
<@include_page path='/FooServlet' params={'itemType': 'component', 'id': '92', 'componentURI': 'foo:92-20975', 'templateURI': 'ttt:92-1082-32','lazyLoad':'enabled' }/>

I want to replace it with 

<#-- <@include_page path='/FooServlet' params={'itemType': 'component', 'id': '92', 'componentURI': 'foo:92-20975', 'templateURI': 'ttt:92-1082-32','lazyLoad':'enabled' }/> -->
```

I was able to delete the line with 
`find . -type f -exec sed -i '/20975/d' {} \;`

**However, I need to comment it out the line that cotains `20975`**

Likewise, I will need to remove the comment out afterwards.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: `sed '/20975/s/^/<#-- /'`

Comment: Try `sed - i '/20975/s/.*/<#-- & -->/' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/.*20975.*/<#-- & -->/' file
```

Comment: I'm surprised and a little bit disappointed to see this kind of an answer from someone with 85k reputation.

Comment: @Pete You have GOT to be kidding. This is absolutely basic, completely fundamental `sed`. If you think it needs ANY kind of explanatory text you are utterly wrong.

Comment: @EdMorton If it is absolutely basic, completely fundamental `sed` then this question does not belong here to begin with and should not be answered.

Comment: @Pete who are you to decide which questions should be asked and answered?

Comment: Not me - it is community consensus that low-quality, poorly researched questions should not be answered to maintain the site's quality. You should know that.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for taking the time to provide answer to this question.